# Retrieving input data after page redirection using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form, that takes the first players name, and the second players name, and then a submit button, which redirects them to the main game screen.

Im attempting to display the players name of whose turn it is after each move. But it keeps saying undefined.

Any ideas?

Heres the HTML:

```html
<h1 id="start">Welcome to Noah's Connect Four Game!</h1>
<form action="gamescreen.html" method="POST">
    <label for="p1">Enter Player One's Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="p1" placeholder= "Player One" ><br><br>
    <label for="p2">Enter Player Two's Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="p2" placeholder= "Player Two"><br><br>
    <input type=submit value ="Play Now!">
</form>
```

and heres the Javascript
(The paragraph tag its referencing is on the main game screen (The one the user is redirected to after submission.)

```js
let turn = '';

var usrOne = $('#p1').val();
var usrTwo = $('#p2').val();

$('td').click(function() {
    if (turn == 'Red'){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
        $(this).text("Red");
        console.log("Red");
        $('p').text(`Its ${usrOne} Turn! Place your blue chip in one of the columns!`);
        turn = 'Blue';
    }
    else{
        $(this).css("background-color","#3f5c94");
        $(this).text("Blue");
        console.log("Blue");
        $('p').text(`Its ${usrTwo} Turn! Place your blue chip in one of the columns!`);
        turn = "Red"
    }
})
```

I feel as if the input is being lost after the user hits the submit button, but i'm using the Post method? Im a bit new to JS and HTML as you can tell.
Thanks!

Comment: share the code of the submition, what are you doing with the inputs value when you submit?, general when you click submit the page is refresh and the input value is getting empty, you need to prevent it, please share the submission code if exist

Comment: @Elnatanvazana I don't believe i have anything else to share, Id like the user input from the text boxes to be displayed on the screen whenever its that particular users turn - thats what i'm doing when i'm editing the text of the p tag on the javascript.

Comment: so you dont need the input type=submit, if it does nothing. if it does something and you have event listener on it so do preventDefault. or just change this to ```<input type="button" value ="Play Now!">``` so it will not refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using a server-side language like PHP, then you'll have to use the query parameters from the URL and JavaScript.

You can start by changing `method="POST"` to `method="GET"`, and adding `name="p1"` and `name="p2"` for your respective inputs. As a note, I'd recommend *always* wrapping attribute values in quotes. I corrected `type=submit` to `type="submit"` for you.

This will be on the first page.

```html
<form action="gamescreen.html" method="GET">
  <label for="p1">Enter Player One's Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="p1" id="p1" placeholder= "Player One" ><br><br>
  <label for="p2">Enter Player Two's Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="p2" id="p2" placeholder= "Player Two"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value ="Play Now!">
</form>
```

This will be on the second page.

```html
<h3>Player 1</h3>
<p id="p1"></p>

<h3>Player 2</h3>
<p id="p2"></p>
```

This also goes into the second page, but just before the `</body>` (the *closing* body) tag.

```js
<script>
/*
  gets the query parameters from the URL, removes the "?" and splits the string 
  into an array based on how many "&" characters were passed.
  Example: "?p1=test+1&p2=test+2" into ["p1=test+1", "p2="test+2"]
*/
var params = document.location.search && document.location.search.replace('?', '').split('&') || '';
// if params was not falsey
if (params) {
  // turns "p1=test+1" into "test 1"
  var player1 = decodeURIComponent(params[0].split('=')[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  // turns "p2=test+2" into "test 2"
  var player2 = decodeURIComponent(params[1].split('=')[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  // inserts the player1 value as the <p id="p1"> value
  document.querySelector('#p1').innerHTML = player1;
  // inserts the player2 value as the <p id="p2"> value
  document.querySelector('#p2').innerHTML = player2;
}
</script>
```